# Rewrite Rule to redirect the whole website except one route

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm migrating a website from, let's say `example.com` to `yyy.com`.

But `example.com/a`, and everything like `example.com/a/*` should stay at `example.com`.

But there's something more: I have routes called something like `example.com/a-b/*`, and this should be redirected to `yyy.com/a-b/*` (like the rest of the website).

I'm able to get the website to correctly redirect everything except `example.com/a*`, but this means `example.com/a-b` is not redirected...

I tried to write the following rules in my .htaccess, in vain:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^a$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^a\/.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.yyy.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

or even:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^a-b
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.yyy.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^a
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.yyy.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

(Changing my route name is not an option)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following in your .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#if it starts with routes a-b then send to yyy
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(a-b/.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule . http://www.yyy.com/%1 [R=301,L]

#if it does not start with an a, then also send to new site
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/a [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.yyy.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: In this case, nothing is redirected

Comment: I assume that these the only rules in your .htaccess file? Can you give me a couple of sample URLs that you tested with.  Thanks

Comment: Yes, they are the only rules, and I tested with http://www.xxx.com/c/d for example

Comment: That is really quite odd. When I put just those rules in my .htaccess file, in the root of my domain, and try  `domain.com/c/d`, `domain.com/a-b/` and `domain.com/a`, the first 2 redirect and the third doesn't, all as expected. There must be something different between our configurations that is not immediately obvious...